# Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel: causes app to crash

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I'm currently working on a workout tracking app, trying to implement a room database of exercises for the user to look at, but whenever I navigate to my database screen, the app crashes with this error message:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.ironlog.MainViewModel
Here is the how I'm initializing my database and viewmodel (then passing them to my navigation components)

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    lateinit var db: ExerciseDatabase


    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        db = ExerciseDatabase.getInstance(this)
        setContent {
            val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>(factoryProducer = {
                MainViewModelFactory(db.dao)
            })
```

this is my ViewModelFactory

```
class MainViewModelFactory(val dao: ExerciseDao) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel::class.java)) {
            return MainViewModel(dao) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

Then this is how I am using the passed arguments in my databasesScreen Composable:

```
@Composable
fun DatabaseScreen(
    state: ExerciseState,
    onEvent: (ExerciseEvent) -> Unit
){
    val viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
    val searchText by viewModel.searchText.collectAsState()
    val exercises by viewModel.exercises.collectAsState(emptyList())
    val categorizedExercises: List<Category> = exercises
        .groupBy { it.exerciseName.first() }
        .toSortedMap()
        .map { entry ->
            Category(
                name = entry.key.toString(),
                items = entry.value
            )
        }
```

Have tried initializing the db and viewModel variables in different ways, but everytime the app ends up crashing whenever I try to navigate to my databaseScreen

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a dependency injection framwork like Hilt? That would do all that for you.